# Where Exists query returning incorrect results

Tags: sql

The inner query here returns values that only appear in one of the tables.  The outer query is supposed to return a count of those.  Instead, it returns the entire table, not just the NULL values.

```
select count(*) from tblicd
where exists
(
select i.icd_id
from tblicd i left outer join icd_jxn on icd_jxn.icd_id=i.icd_id
where icd_jxn.icd_id is null
)
```

The inner query

```
select i.icd_id
    from tblicd i left outer join icd_jxn on icd_jxn.icd_id=i.icd_id
    where icd_jxn.icd_id is null
```

works and does what I want.  I'd like (using a sub query method like this) to use the outer query to just return the number of rows that the inner query returns.

Comment: Without the outer query I get a list of all the icd_id codes that appear in tblICD that do NOT appear in icd_jxn.  This works fine.  The outer query I want to just return that number.  I want to use a subquery for this to become familiar with them.

Comment: now you don't have a reference to the original `tblicd` in the subquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the two (outer and inner) `tblicd` tables in the subquery:

```
and i.icd_id = tblicd.icd_id
```

(or whatever the id of the `tblicd` table is)

Comment: ah, perfect.  knew i was missing something menial.

Comment: `exists` is a bit overkill to "return the number of rows that the inner query returns"

Comment: @wootscootinboogie speaking of learning process, "menial" is the the word you taught me today :)

Comment: Your new-found English altiloquence will surely dissuade any varlet's attempts at upbraiding you for having a parochial vocabulary :)

Answer (score 1):

The query you posted doesn't make any sense. However, from your description, it sounds like you've got two tables and you're trying to find any IDs that don't exist in both tables. If that's correct, you should try something like this:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from table1 t1 
     full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null
      or t2.id is null
```

This may not work in the database you're using, but since you didn't tell us that, we can't tailor the solution to fit your dialect of SQL.

---

Based on the revised question, you could simplify this a number of ways:

```
select count(*) 
from tblicd 
where not exists (select i.icd_id
                  from icd_jxn
                  where icd_jxn.icd_id = tblicd)

select count(tblicd.icd_id)
from tblicd 
     left join
     icd_jxn
     on tblicd.icd_id = icd_jxn.icd_id
where icd_jxn.icd_id is null

select count(tblicd.icd_id)
from tblicd
where icd_id not in (select icd_id 
                     from icd_jxn)
```

Basically, there's no reason to select from `tblicd` twice.

Comment: So I can help better write questions in the future, what about my query didn't make sense (after I edited it)?

Comment: It makes sense now. When I wrote that it was in an intermediate state.